# $$.ajax is not a function

Tags: html-framework-7, dom7

i tried framework7 Custom DOM library and i run one of the example

```
$$.ajax({
  url: 'somepage.html',
  statusCode: {
    404: function (xhr) {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
})
```

but it return error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $$.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:11)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handleEvent (framework7.js:967)
    at sendClick (framework7.js:3589)
    at Framework7.handleTouchEnd (framework7.js:3779)
    at framework7.js:2619
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at framework7.js:2618
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Framework7.emit (framework7.js:2616)
    at emitAppTouchEvent (framework7.js:3856)
```

does anyone know how to use Dom7 Custom Library ?

i already tried to Export DOM7 to local variable to make it easy accessable

```
var $$ = Dom7;
```

i also tried to include Dom7.js in my script

```
<script src="node_modules/dom7/dist/dom7.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also ran into this same problem just now, not found a way out yet... once i find a solution, i will share

Answer (score 0):

Got it working right now

In v2 it is `myApp.request({...})`

`var xhr =app.request({

```
    method: method,
    url: url,
    contentType: contentType,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {

        form.trigger('beforeSubmit', {data:data, xhr: xhr});
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        form.trigger('submitError', {data:data, xhr: xhr});
    },
    success: function (data) {
        form.trigger('submitted', {data: data, xhr: xhr});

        }, 2000);




    }
});`
```